How to run command in WHILE-DO bash command
I'm trying to run echo in a loop in which the wait time varies. The following command does already do this
/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do echo test; sleep 10 ; done;'"

However, I don't it to be 10 seconds all the time, I want it to be a random number between 1 and 10. To generate a random number between 1 and 10 I constructed the following
$> min=1 && max=10
$> echo $(($RANDOM%($max-$min+1)+$min))

Now, my question is, how do I combine this. For example, I tried the following
$> /bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do echo test; sleep $(($RANDOM%($max-$min+1)+$min)) ; done;'"

But this gives errors
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `trap exit TERM; while :; do echo test; min=1 && max=10 && sleep $RANDOM%($max-$min+1)+$min ; done;

Any suggestions how to combine the two? Or if there is a better way, I'm also all ears!!

Cannot reproduce the error shown.

Why is it tagged bash, if you don't run bash? Please replace the bash tag by either sh  or shell.

In the first example you don't declare min,max so it will error. In the second example you don't wrap the arithmetic in $((...)) so it will also error.

Also FYI, inside $(( )) expressions you can use variable names without the $ sign

Apparently max and min are not exported and so they are undefined in the subshell.
Try
bash -c 'max=10; min=1; trap exit TERM; while :; do echo test; sleep $(($RANDOM%($max-$min+1)+$min)); done'

Alternatively, export the variables you want to make visible to subprocesses.
(If your sh implements RANDOM the way Bash does, then of course feel free to use sh instead; but this is not portable or recommended. See also Difference between Bash and sh)
